# INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint (check with UDF)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on inventory management system where I have to relate sale line items to purchase line items in order to calculate profit. in order to keep track of available item by purchase line, I wrote a function and used it in a `CHECK` constraint but insert query is conflicting despite of less quantity than available quantity.

I have tried changing `[Qty]`, half or less of available quantity inserts successfully however equal amount or one less does not work.

Here is my table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tSaleLineItem]
(
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [proId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Qty] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Price] [FLOAT] NOT NULL,
    [PurchaseId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [BIT] NOT NULL
)
```

My check constraint condition

```
[dbo].[fnGetStockByPurchase]([PurchaseId]) >= [Qty]
```

and my function is defined as

```
RETURN 
    (ISNULL((SELECT Qty FROM tPurchaseLineItem 
             WHERE Id = @PurchaseId AND IsActive = 1), 0)
    - ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM tSaleLineItem 
              WHERE PurchaseId = @PurchaseId AND IsActive = 1), 0))
```

This is what I am trying

```
SELECT * 
FROM tPurchaseLineItem

SELECT dbo.fnGetStockByPurchase(4)

INSERT INTO tSaleLineItem(InvoiceId, proId,Qty,Price, PurchaseId) 
VALUES (2, 1, 10, 100, 4)
```

Messages tab shows

```
(3 rows affected)

(1 row affected)
```

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 7
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_tSaleLineItem_Qty". The conflict occurred in database "testDb", table "dbo.tSaleLineItem".

Result tab shows

```
Id  InvoiceId   proId   Qty Price   IsActive
--------------------------------------------
4   2           1       10  100     1
5   2           1       10  100     1
6   2           1       10  100     1

(No column name)
10
```

I want my current `INSERT` query to insert data as `[Qty]` is equal to available quantity.

Comment: Before your INSERT, what rows already exist in `tSaleLineItem` for PurchaseID 4?

Comment: You might find more SQL expertise at dba.stackexchange.com if your question does not get answered here.

Comment: @TabAlleman right now no row is existing, this is in case of some quantity is already sold like in this scenario, the function will return 5 if i have a row of [Qty] value of 5.

Comment: Very common mistake: the row is inserted, *then* the `CHECK` happens, *then* the transaction is rolled back if the check fails to hold. You must take care to make the `CHECK` work with the new row(s) already included (usually, by explicitly excluding it from consideration).

Comment: Also, take care that a `CHECK` must logically *always* hold in every possible state of the database; if it does not, the engine can get cranky and you can get very mysterious failures. If you have checks that cross tables and can get invalidated by operations on other tables, what you really want is triggers (or stored procedures that encapsulate the logic). Using a function in a `CHECK` to circumvent the requirement that a `CHECK` should only use the columns of a single row is usually a sign that you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @JeroenMostert i'm new to database, can you please help me with this by providing some study links or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged the function body by converting into following block

```
DECLARE @PurchaseId INT;
DECLARE @Qty INT;
DECLARE @QtyP INT;
DECLARE @QtyS INT;
SET @PurchaseId=4;
SET @Qty =10;

SELECT @QtyS =  ISNULL(SUM(Qty),0) FROM tSaleLineItem 
         WHERE PurchaseId = @PurchaseId AND IsActive = 1;
SELECT @QtyP =  ISNULL(SUM(Qty),0) FROM tPurchaseLineItem 
         WHERE Id = @PurchaseId AND IsActive = 1;
PRINT 'QtyP';
PRINT @QtyP;
PRINT 'QtyS';
PRINT @QtyS;
PRINT 'QtyP-QtyS';
PRINT @QtyP - @QtyS

IF((@QtyP-@QtyS)>=@Qty)
          PRINT 'True';
ELSE
          PRINT 'False';
```

what i found is order of `SUM()` and `ISNULL()`. In my question I have written it as `ISNULL(SUM))` which resulted in null while `SUM(ISNULL())` resulted in zero although in both cases there is no row in `tSaleLineItem`.
The Above block resulted in

> ```
> QtyP
> 10
> QtyS
> 0
> QtyP-QtyS
> 10
> True
> ```

although I am still wondering why it inserted half or less quantity, though it is not the headache now.

The summary is still blowing my mind. I cannot understand this too.

```
DECLARE @QtyS INT;

SELECT @QtyS =  SUM(ISNULL(Qty,0)) FROM tSaleLineItem 
PRINT 'QtyS';
PRINT @QtyS;

SELECT @QtyS =  ISNULL(SUM(Qty),0) FROM tSaleLineItem 
PRINT 'QtyS';
PRINT @QtyS;
```

the output is

> ```
> QtyS
>
> QtyS
> 0
> ```

However,
Thank you all for your valuable comments and help.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
RETURN 
(ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM tSaleLineItem 
         WHERE Id = @PurchaseId AND IsActive = 1), 0)
- ISNULL((SELECT Qty FROM tPurchaseLineItem 
          WHERE PurchaseId = @PurchaseId AND IsActive = 1), 0))
```

Because if you have two Purchases function returns negative value and hence constraint violation

Comment: Id in tPurchaseLineItem is Primary key so SUM() does not affect the output